# In IOS 6.0 : UIBarButton in bottom toolbar disappears after presenting and dismissing modal view controller

Tags: ios

This worked fine in IOS 5 and it's not working after upgrading to the latest xcode. We have a view controller with a bottom toolbar which has two bar button items"save" and"cancel". Pressing another button launches a modal view controller and when the modal view controller is dismissed to come back to the original view controller, the save and cancel buttons seems to have disappeared. The toolbar still shows . This is so weird that we don't even know where to start. Any pointers/suggestions appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: @uuser1306828 can you put your code here?

Comment: Thanks for responding! Well, the toolbar and the Save Cancel buttons are created in storyboard. So, I'm not sure what code you would like to see.

Comment: I'm having this kinda trouble, and the toolbar in my project is created for the footer view for a table view.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a pretty big bug so I'm thinking there is just something going on in your code.

Try creating a blank project in xcode with nothing but a view with toolbar and buttons that show your modal view.

If you don't see any issues then you must be doing something in code to cause it.